# There are 30 marathon runners, 5 distinct trophies, how many different ways to distribute them such that two person jack and jim are included.

Tags: combinatorics

There are 30 marathon runners, 5 distinct trophies, how many different ways to distribute them such that two person jack and jim are must be included.

Still new to combinatorics, a question I came up with but not sure whether I have gotten the right answer.

: **P(5,2) * P(30-2,5-2) = P(5,2) * P(28,3)**

Am I doing this right? 
Still pretty confused on whether should I use Combination on jack and jim instead of Permutation. But I would guess that it should be permutation since the trophies are different, am I right to imply it this way?

Comment: Could one player win more than one trophy?

Comment: nope, only one per winner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jack needs one of the 5 cups, so we have 5 choices for that. Jim needs one of the remaining 4, so 4 choices after that.

Then we have three cups, to divide among 28 other runners, so $28 \times 27 \times 26$ options.

So in total $5 \times 4 \times 28 \times 27 \times 26$ options.

I am assuming a runner can win only one cup.